# Detecting the Team Project Collection in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm using the Team Foundation Server API to try to connect to a remote server.

From within my application, I try to connect to a URL of the form https://some-tfs-location.example.com/tfs but when doing so I get an error TF50309 (discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/d0b7207a-86ce-4646-bc7d-7eec3b2465f5/)).  If I add the project collection to the end of the URL (so the path becomes `tfs/101`) then I can connect with no problems.

I'd like to try and mimic the behaviour of Visual Studio, where I can give it a URL without needing to specify the project collection and it'll connect and locate the project collection.

Does anyone have any suggestions which API's I can use to mimic the Visual Studio behaviour?  I had hoped to find the project collection via

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(projectRoot.ServerUrl,new MyCredentials());
var projectCollection = ttpc.CatalogNode.FullPath;
```

But this results in the same TF50309 error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [TfsConfigurationServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsconfigurationserver.aspx) class with the server Uri that has no team project collection (e.g. http://localhost:8080/tfs), get the [ITeamProjectCollectionService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iteamprojectcollectionservice.aspx) service, and use GetCollections method or GetDefaultCollection method to retrieve the collection you want.

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/01/26/retrieve-the-list-of-team-project-collections-from-tfs-2010-client-apis.aspx) described it in more details.